# How can I get facebook photo like count in iPhone SDK?

Tags: ios5, ios4

How can I get the count of facebook photo likes and dislikes in an iPhone application using graph api?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call a new request with the FB object:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"PHOTO_ID/likes"];
```

Replace `PHOTO_ID` with the Facebook ID of the photo you're interested in.  This call will return an array with all like information for that photo.

In the `-facebook requestDidLoad:` method, just get the count of that array to return the number of likes.

`NSInteger likeCount = [result count];`

Comment: No problem. If you're satisfied with my answer, please mark it as correct by clicking the checkmark to the left.